# JNI unresolved external symbol __imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM in 64 bit compiler

Tags: java, visual-c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create JVM usin JNI. I'm using win 7 64 bits OS. On line JNI_CreateJavaVM my program crashes. I decided to compile my program using 64 bit compiler and got following error:

`Error  1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM`

Where is the point I should start to look for linking problem and why my program crashes in 32 bit mode?

```
void createJVM()
{

JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; 
JavaVMOption options[4]; 

int n = 0;     
char * str;
str= new char[1000];
sprintf(str, "-Djava.class.path=%S\\tst.jar", myPath);
options[n++].optionString = str; 

str= new char[1000];
sprintf(str, "-Djava.library.path=%S\\lib;%S", myPath, myPath);
options[n++].optionString = str;

str= new char[1000];
sprintf(str, "-Duser.dir=%S", myPath);
options[n++].optionString = str;

vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
vm_args.nOptions = n;     
vm_args.options = options;     
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;


JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

have you added 'jvm.lib' as Additional Dependency in your project?
furthermore, you need to specify the location of jvm.lib in Additional Library Directories...

also please note that for 64-bit application, you would need to point to the 64-bit library, otherwise linker won't link

You can find those settings in the Configuration Properties->Linker area.

hope this information helps you out.

Cheers,

Comment: I added the path to the jvm.lib to the two project properties you mentioned but I still get this linker error. Do have any more hints? Do I need to add any Java DLL to the project or something?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't wote up (still less than 15 reputation) I just want to confirm that Naytzyrhc solution worked for me.

Just to clarify it a bit more, in **Visual Studio Express 2013 (v12)** you should go to:

```
Project -> [YourProjectName] Properties... -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories
```

for adding lib folder to additional library directories, and:

```
Project -> [YourProjectName] Properties... -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies
```

for adding jvm.lib to additional dependencies.